# android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException with android 4.2 error

Tags: android

Here i am using JSONparser class but i am getting error on return jObj is "Type mismatch: cannot convert from JSONObject to String"

How to solve this

I am searching for the solution from last 1 months but no luck

```
public class JSONParser extends AsyncTask <String, Void, String>{

static InputStream is = null;

static JSONObject jObj = null;
static String json = "";

// constructor
public JSONParser() {

}
@Override
protected String doInBackground(String... params) {


// Making HTTP request
try {
    // defaultHttpClient
    DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
    HttpGet httpPost = new HttpGet(url);

        HttpResponse getResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
       final int statusCode = getResponse.getStatusLine().getStatusCode();

       if (statusCode != HttpStatus.SC_OK) { 
          Log.w(getClass().getSimpleName(), 
              "Error " + statusCode + " for URL " + url); 
          return null;
       }

       HttpEntity getResponseEntity = getResponse.getEntity();

    //HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
    //HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
    is = getResponseEntity.getContent();            

} catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
} catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
} catch (IOException e) {
    Log.d("IO", e.getMessage().toString());
    e.printStackTrace();

}

try {
    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
            is, "iso-8859-1"), 8);
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    String line = null;
    while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
        sb.append(line + "\n");
    }
    is.close();
    json = sb.toString();
} catch (Exception e) {
    Log.e("Buffer Error", "Error converting result " + e.toString());
}

// try parse the string to a JSON object
try {
    jObj = new JSONObject(json);
} catch (JSONException e) {
    Log.e("JSON Parser", "Error parsing data " + e.toString());
}

// return JSON String
return jObj;


}
protected void onPostExecute(String page)
{   
 //onPostExecute
}   
}
```

Comment: Put the code you call this AsyncTask.

Comment: the code is already pasted here 

error i am getting is  on return jObj is "Type mismatch: cannot convert from JSONObject to String"

Comment: I am asking for the JSONParser instantiation and the task execution.

Answer (score 1):

Change your class to:

```
public class JSONParser extends AsyncTask <String, Void, JSONObject>
```

doInBackground to:

```
@Override
protected JSONObject doInBackground(String... params) {
}
```

onPostExecute to:

```
protected void onPostExecute(JSONObject result) {
}
```

**EDIT:**

Pass result to MainActivity:

Create interface in `JSONParser` class:

```
public interface OnResponseListener{
    public void onResponse(JSONObject result); 
}


OnResponseListener mListener;

public setOnResponseListener(OnResponseListener listener){
     mListener = listener;
}
```

Edit onPostExecute:

```
protected void onPostExecute(JSONObject result) {
    mListener.onResponse(result);
}
```

In MainActivity implement interface:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements IResponse{
    ...
    task.setOnResponseListener(this);
    ...

    public void onResponse(JSONObject result) {
          //do stuff with result
         }

}
```

Comment: can you tell me how to pass json object in MainActivity like 

     JSONParser jParser = new JSONParser();

                
     JSONObject json =      jParser.doInBackground();

??

Comment: @Rajdeep Kumar manipulate `result` in `onPostExecute`. If you want to use it in MainActivity - create interface in `AsyncTask` class and implement it in `MainActivity`

Comment: can you please help me to create interface in AsyncTask with some sample code ?? :)